# How to read space separated numbers from console?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

I'm trying to do a simple task of reading space separated numbers from console into a `vector<int>`, but I'm not getting how to do this properly.

This is what I have done till now:

```
int n = 0;
vector<int> steps;
while(cin>>n)
{
    steps.push_back(n);
}
```

However, this requires the user to press an invalid character (such as `a`) to break the `while` loop. I don't want it.

As soon as user enters numbers like `0 2 3 4 5` and presses `Enter` I want the loop to be broken. I tried using `istream_iterator` and `cin.getline` also, but I couldn't get it working.

I don't know how many elements user will enter, hence I'm using `vector`.

Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a `getline` combined with an `istringstream` to extract the numbers.

```
std::string input;
getline(cin, input);
std::istringstream iss(input);
int temp;
while(iss >> temp)
{
   yourvector.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: But that method requires streamsize which I don't know. Can you post a sample code?

Comment: Oops..ok, I got it now with @templatetypedef example. You are referring to free function `geline` and not `cin.getline`.

Comment: #include <sstream> otherwise you will get an error "istringstream iss has initializer but incomplete type"

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on jonsca's answer, here is one possibility, assuming that the user faithfully enters valid integers:

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);

istringstream parser(input);
vector<int> numbers;

numbers.insert(numbers.begin(),
               istream_iterator<int>(parser), istream_iterator<int>());
```

This will correctly read and parse a valid line of integers from `cin`.  Note that this is using the *free function* `getline`, which works with `std::string`s, and not `istream::getline`, which works with C-style strings.

Answer (score 2):

This code should help you out, it reads a line to a string and then iterates over it getting out all numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream in(line, std::istringstream::in);
    int n;
    vector<int> v;
    while (in >> n) {
        v.push_back(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, might be helpful to know that you can stimulate an EOF - Press 'ctrl-z' (windows only, unix-like systems use ctrl-d) in the command line, after you have finished with your inputs. Should help you when you're testing little programs like this - without having to type in an invalid character.

Comment: That would be Ctrl-d on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

Prompt user after each number or take number count in advance and loop accordingly.
Not a great idea but i saw this in many applications.