# How to read space and newline separated integers into a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file of numbers (in this case all less than 100) separated by spaces, in rows separated by new lines. Something like this:

```
 41 53 07 91 44
 52 17 13 03 21
```

I would like to read these numbers into a 2d array, exactly as they appear, so that spaces separate columns of the array, and new lines separate rows.

I can get it to read the lines in as strings, but then I'm having trouble separating out individual numbers, and getting it to treat them as integers.

Comment: Show us your code so we can point out what is wrong or give you hints on how to continue.

Comment: Do you have the sizes of the array upfront? That is, do you know that there are 5 columns, or is that dependent on the input file? What is your definition of *array* (i.e. must it be an actual *array* as `int data[100][5]`, or *dynamically allocated* array, or can it be a container like `std::vector<int>`)

Comment: talnicolas: yes, sorry, I'll remember to include what I have for next time (I was using the "getline" command, as it happens.

David: I do know the size (20*20), but I'd quite like to write the program such that it would work for other sizes. The dynamically allocated array idea seems better to me.

Comment: For each line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497277/how-to-read-space-separated-numbers-from-console

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // The result of the read is placed in here
    // In C++, we use a vector like an array but vectors can dynamically grow
    // as required when we get more data.
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >     data;

    // Replace 'Plop' with your file name.
    std::ifstream          file("Plop");

    std::string   line;
    // Read one line at a time into the variable line:
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::vector<int>   lineData;
        std::stringstream  lineStream(line);

        int value;
        // Read an integer at a time from the line
        while(lineStream >> value)
        {
            // Add the integers from a line to a 1D array (vector)
            lineData.push_back(value);
        }
        // When all the integers have been read, add the 1D array
        // into a 2D array (as one line in the 2D array)
        data.push_back(lineData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer makes a lot of sense to me. I guessed that you meant lineData.push_back(value) in the second from last executed line, which works perfectly. What's more, I think I understand why! So am I right in think that the >> operator on a stringstream extracts a number until it reaches whitespace, and moves itself to the start of the next number ready to extract it in the future?

Comment: @SamElliott: Not quite. The operator>> when applied to an integer will: 1) drop all whitespace from the stream. 2) If the first non white space character is NOT an integer it will mark the stream as bad, otherwise it it will read the next 'n' characters that make an integer (stopping at the first non integer character (which may be white space))

Comment: For those who are new to c++, you'll also need to include the `string`, `iostream`, and `sstream` headers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the "exactly as they appear" requirement means that you need a ragged array, in case different number of columns appear in different rows.  I would use `std::vector< std::vector<long> >`.  Each contained vector corresponds to one row.

So, each time you read a row of text, create a new empty vector.

Call `strtol` repeatedly on the row you read, using `push_back` to collect them into the vector.  When the output pointer is the same as the input pointer (this indicates failure, probably because you reached the end of the line), `push_back` the whole vector and start the next row.

Something like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<long> > all_data;

std::string text_row;

while(getline(fin, text_row)) {
    all_data.push_back();
    std::vector<long>& this_row = *all_data.rend();

    const char* p1 = text_row.c_str();
    const char* p2;
    while (1) {
         long num = strtol(p2 = p1, &p1, 0);
         if (p1 == p2) break;
         this_row.push_back(num);
    }

    /* to ignore blank lines, add this code
    if (this_row.empty()) all_data.pop_back();
     */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how to solve your problem. It also shows how you can use RAII when opening a file. This is good practice when acquiring resources. By acquiring the resource in the constructor and releasing it in the destructor a resource leak can be prevented if an exeption is thrown. This is considered good practice in the C++ world.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct FileHandle
{
  std::ifstream file_;
  FileHandle(std::string file_name)
  {
    file_.open(file_name);
  }
  ~FileHandle()
  {
    file_.close();
  }
};

bool next_char_is_end_of_line(std::ifstream &file)
{
  bool found = false;
  char c;
  file.get(c);
  if(c == '\n')
    found = true;
  file.unget();
  return found;
}

int main()
{
  FileHandle fh("c:\\your_file.txt");
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;
  std::vector<int> current_line;
  int x;
  while(fh.file_ >> x)
  {
    current_line.push_back(x);
    if(next_char_is_end_of_line(fh.file_))
    {
      v.push_back(current_line);
      current_line.clear();
    }
  }
  //Then just access each std::vector<std::vector<int>> 
  //v[0].size(); ...
  return 0;
}
```

This code gives you a "jagged" vector by putting all numbers on each row into a separate vector. This vector is then added to main vector. So each line in the "vector" can have different lengths. I think you get the idea...

Good luck!

Comment: Though I like your enthusiasm for RAII the std::fstream already does this. The constructor can take a string and the destructor automatically calls close() (but it also catches and discards exceptions which yours does not).

Comment: @LokiAstari I had totally missed that fstream does that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Comment: Answers for beginners usually involves a simple example, or at least a detailed explanation of how he could achieve his goal using your technique.

Comment: @talnicolas, true, but I was heading out the door, the link points to a concise and complete example, and Loki Astari covered it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two problems, here:

1. how to recognize the input and ...
2. how to represent it in memory.

You spoke about "2d Array": is this a requirement or just an hypothesis? is the 2x5 size a requirement or just a sample?

You spoke about a file layout. It that mandatory, or not? Must you admit (and check) eventually misleading like more numbers, or misalignment? What do you have to do in case the row have 6 numbers the first and 4 the second?

A very simple solution can be use a 2x5 array and fill it up with a guarded loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

const int ROWS=2;
const int COLS=5;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int m[ROWS][COLS];
    try
    {
        std::ifstream s(argv[1]);
        if(!s) throw std::runtime_error("cannot open file");
        for(int r=0; r<ROWS; ++r)
            for(int c=0; c<COLS; ++c)
               if(!(s >>m[r][c])
                   throw std::runtime_error("insufficient or bad input");
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Reading error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "read matrix is \n";
    for(int r=0; r<ROWS; ++r)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<COLS; ++c)
            std::cout << std::setw(8) << m[r][c];
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will read 10 numbers separated by "blanks", no matter how distributed and aligned.
(it is assumend the the 2x5 is a consrain.)

On the other end, you may have to detect yourself how wide the matrix is: the file can have any number of lines, each whatever number of elements long.

In this case you need a "flexible structure", and you need to identify lines and elements in the lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > m;
    try
    {
        std::ifstream fs(argv[1]);
        if(!fs) throw std::runtime_error("cannot open input file");
        while(fs)
        {
            std::string line;
            std::getline(fs,line);
            std::vector<int> row;
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            int x;
            while(ss >> x)
               row.push_back(x); 
            if(!row.empty())
                m.emplace_back(std::move(row));
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Reading error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "read lines: \n";
    for(auto i=m.begin(); i!=m.end(); ++i)
    {
        for(auto j=i->begin(); j!=i->end(); ++j)
            std::cout << std::setw(8) << *j;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though you compensate for `while(fs)` and `while(ss)` by checking the sate of the stream inside the loop. This is not the idiomatic way to read from a stream: Try `while(ss >> x)` which reads the integer from the stream. On failure the loop will not be entered.

Comment: You can also do `while(std::getline(fs, line))`.