# Read file and input into vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Given a text file with the following fixed contents (only two lines, nothing more):

```
43 65 123 13 41
83 67 22
```

I need it to turn into a vector array where I can apply the name.size() to find out the length of the array and also to make use of the integers inside for other purposes.

The result should be:

```
Array 1: 43 65 123 13 41
Array 2: 83 67 22

Array 1 Length: 5
Array 2 Length: 3
```

I have successfully read the text file and added the content using .push_back(). However when I cout the vector .size(), it returns 2 and I realised that it consider each line as an element in the array.

What is the approach to tackling this?

Edit:

Added snippet of the code:

```
vector <string> readFile(const string& fileName)
{
    ifstream source;
    source.open(filename);
    vector <string> lines;
    string line;

    while(getline(source, line)
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    } return lines;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string inputFile(argv[1]);
    vector <string> fileData = readFile(inputFile);
    
    // Check vector
    for(auto i : fileData)
        cout << i << endl;

    // Check vector length
    cout << fileData.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please include your attempt in the form of a [mcve]. And if the contents of the file will always be two lines, why not use a fixed-size array of vectors instead, like e.g. `std::array<std::vector<int>, 2>`?

Comment: This can be done with [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: As above. There are two parts to this task, first you read each line, and then you read each integer from each line. Does the code you wrote do this? Hard to say since you haven't posted your code. Always post your code.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file space separated integers".  There are too many similar questions on StackOverflow already.

Comment: IMHO, your best method is to read one line as text, use `std::istringstream` to extract the numbers into a vector.  Assign this vector to the outer one.

Comment: Added my snippet of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read space and newline separated integers into a 2D array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570991/how-to-read-space-and-newline-separated-integers-into-a-2d-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) are good starting points.

Then you can use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to create the vectors directly using the iterator overload of [the `std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> read_file(std::istream& input)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> lines;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
        std::istringstream line_stream(line);

        lines.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<int>(line_stream),
                           std::istream_iterator<int>());
    }

    return lines;
}
```

This handles an arbitrary number of lines containing an arbitrary number of integer values.

---

Can be used something like this:

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    auto data = read_file(input);

    std::cout << "First line of data: ";
    for (auto value : data[0])
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Second line of data: ";
    for (auto value : data[1])
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Important note: The example above lacks any kind of error or range checking. It's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hi, thanks I am trying out the code but not too sure how should I call it in my main function? vector <string> fileData = read_file(inputFile); does not seem to work as it says it has invalid initialization of reference type

Comment: @user3118602 Added example on how it could be used, relevant to your data.

Comment: @user3118602 Regarding the error, what is the return type of my function? What is the type of your `fileData` variable?

Comment: Thanks. I think I managed to make it work using a modified method, with some reference from your answer. I will mark this as the answer since it assisted me to get to my solution! C++ is a nightmare! T_T

Answer (score 0):

You could read each one as a text line, then extract the numbers from the text.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> database;
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(cin, text_line))
{
  std::vector<int> numbers_row;
  std::istringstream number_stream(text_line);
  int value;
  while (number_stream >> value)
  {
      numbers_row.push_back(value);
  }
  database.push_back(numbers_row);
}
```

The inner loop creates a vector based on the numbers in that text line.
The outer loop creates vectors and appends them to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to use `std::getline` to read line by line, to put it in a `std::istringstream` and then to use formatted input from that stream - but you've already gotten answers for that so I'll throw in an alternative.

This uses formatted input directly from the `ifstream` (or any `istream` descendant) and `peek()`s to see if a newline (`\n`) is the next character.

It could look like this:

```
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> read_stream(std::istream& is) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
    std::vector<int> cur;
    int x;

    while(true) {
        if(is.peek() == '\n') {
            // save what we've gotten on the current line
            res.emplace_back(std::move(cur));
            cur.clear();
        }

        if(is >> x) cur.push_back(x);
        else break;
    }

    return res;
}
```