# How to use scanf() input unknown number of objects?

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program that read unknown numbers of inputs(only numbers) from strin, with the scanf() function. But it seems not to very plesased to this condition: I input 9, however the program only reads 5 of it.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int top=0,heap[65535];
void add_up(int x){
    int next=x>>1,now=x;
    while(next){
        if(heap[now]<heap[next]){
            heap[now]^=heap[next]^=heap[now]^=heap[next];
            now=next;
            next=now>>1;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return ;
}
void add_down(){
    int now=1,next=now<<1;
    while(next<=top){
        if(next<top&&heap[next]>heap[next+1])next++;
        if(heap[now]<heap[next])break;
        heap[now]^=heap[next]^=heap[now]^=heap[next];
        now=next;
        next=now<<1;
    }
    return ;
}
int main(){
    memset(heap,0,sizeof(heap));
    int i; 
    while(scanf("%d",&i)!=EOF){
//  for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        scanf("%d",&i);
        printf("%d ",i);
        heap[++top]=i;
        add_up(top);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(top>0){
        printf("%d ",heap[1]);
        heap[1]=heap[top--];
        add_down();
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It is amazing to find this:

```
E:\home\Desktop>echo 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 > try001.txt
E:\home\Desktop>gcc -g try001.cc -o try001
E:\home\Desktop>try001.exe < try001.txt
8 6 4 2 1
1 2 4 6 8
E:\home\Desktop>
```

There is 9 numbers in the input file, and why the program only read 5!
While if I wanna read unknown numbers of input, how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497277/reading-space-separated-numbers-from-console

Comment: I just only want to use the cstdio head file, please.

Comment: `heap[now]^=heap[next]^=heap[now]^=heap[next];` causes undefined behaviour , meaning your program could do anything. Try writing correct code instead of attempting to be cool by using hacks

Comment: @TJM: Why? And then why are you writing C++? This is essentially C code.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Because, if I use C, the compiler does not accept it.

Comment: If you have an error in your C code, _fix the error_. Don't just plug it into a C++ compiler instead and hope for the best...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I don't know the grammar of C. What I know is just the C part of C++.

Comment: @TJM: And? So? Therefore?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  So, what I can do is using C grammar with C++ Compiler

Comment: @TJM: Nope that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the use of `scanf` twice instead of once in the following lines:

```
while(scanf("%d",&i)!=EOF){
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d ",i);
```

The number you read in the first call to `scanf` just gets ignored.

Remove the second `scanf` and use just:

```
while(scanf("%d",&i)!=EOF){
    printf("%d ",i);
```

When you have one variable that you are trying to read into, use of

```
while(scanf("%d",&i)!=EOF)
```

is OK. However, when there are more than one variable, it's necessary to use:

```
while ( scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2 )
```

since the return value could be `1` if a value was successfully assigned to only `i`. It's better to use the the same style of coding even when you are trying to read into one variable. Hence, it's preferable to use:

```
while ( scanf("%d", &i) == 1 )
```

Comment: Like this:      while(!scanf("%d",&i)){
// for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
  printf("%d ",i);
  heap[++top]=i;
  add_up(top);
 }

Comment: @TJM, that does not make sense at all. How can it read successfully with two calls to `scanf` but fail with one call to `scanf`?

Comment: E:\home\Desktop>gcc -g try001.cc -o try001
    E:\home\Desktop>try001.exe < try001.txt


    E:\home\Desktop>

Comment: I don't know.[link](http://img.vim-cn.com/19/89a53ea9820af16ecaf4b008c481881b5531b1.png )

Comment: The check needs to be `while ( scanf("%d", &i) == 1) {` or `while ( scanf("%d", &i) != EOF) {`

Comment: Should be `== 1` rather than `!= EOF`